# install 'pip' package for specific version of Python on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have on my machine (windows 10) two versions  of python: 3.5 2.7
I need to install a package using ***pip*** but I want the package on both.

My default version is 3.5.

I try to do this: `pip2 install scikit-learn` to install it on python 2.7  and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.commands import commands, get_similar_commands, get_summaries
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.bundle import BundleCommand
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\bundle.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.req import InstallRequirement, RequirementSet, parse_requirements
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pip.wheel
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url, unpack_url
ImportError: cannot import name unpack_url
```

I also try this: `python2.7 -m pip install scikit-learn`   or `python27 -m pip install scikit-learn` 
and I get this error:

```
python2.7 : The term 'python2.7' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,                  function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify   that the path is correct and try agai
At line:1 char:1
+ python2.7 -m pip install scikit-learn
+ ~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python2.7:String) [],           CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I do have python 2.7 on `C:\Python27`.
What to do?

Comment: Try `C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install scikit-learn` and `C:\python35\scripts\pip.exe install scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use

for python2.x `py -2`
for python3.x `py -3`

so it would be

```
py -2 -m pip install scikit-learn
py -3 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

just try `py --help` for more info

Comment: I try it also..   this what I have: cannot import name unpack_url; 'pip' is a package

Comment: maybe I need to change something in environment variable??

Comment: try `py -3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` just to make sure pip is installed correctly

Comment: @Moti.gadian use -E like in `py -E -2` to ignore environment

Answer (score 1):

The safest and least frustrating way to go about this is to load independent copies of scikit learn into two virtual environments.

Install by:

```
$ pip install virtualenv

$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=<path to python> <name virtualenv>
```

To run it...

```
workon <name virtualenv>
```

Comment: I try do to it and got this:  mkvirtualenv : The term 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  mkvirtualenv --python=C:/python27 env27
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mkvirtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Are you doing this in a terminal or are you trying to run it as a Python script?

Comment: try just `virtualenv <virtual environment name>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks allot for the answers,
after some try&fail I find 2 different ways to figure it.
**1.**  `<PATH-FOR-PYTHON>\scripts\pip.exe install <package name>`

**2.**     
             `py -2 -E-m pip install scikit-learn   for v3.5
             py -3 -E -m pip install scikit-learn  for v2.7`